# how set light and materials to obtain an emerald object

Tags: opengl, light, opengl-compat

When I set the material in opengl for an object (glutSolidSphere(2.,10.,8.);), let for example the emerald parameters:

```
 float[] mat_ambient ={ 0.0215f, 0.1745f, 0.0215f, 0.55f };
 float[] mat_diffuse ={0.07568f, 0.61424f, 0.07568f, 0.55f };
 float[] mat_specular ={0.633f, 0.727811f, 0.633f, 0.55f };
 float shine = 76.8f;
```

In order to obtain really an emerald object I should set the components of light in the same way? I mean:

```
float[] light_ambient ={ 0.0215f, 0.1745f, 0.0215f, 0.55f };
float[] light_diffuse ={0.07568f, 0.61424f, 0.07568f, 0.55f };
float[] light_specular ={0.633f, 0.727811f, 0.633f, 0.55f };
```

float[] light_position= { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 };

The result is not good...

[image]

Comment: If you want to render a green surface with a [Blinn–Phong reflection model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinn%E2%80%93Phong_reflection_model) and [Gouraud shading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouraud_shading) you have found the answer. However, you can't do anything more realistic with the 20-year-old OpenGL  Fixed-Function pipeline. Same reason as in the comments on your previous question [How can I do a brass surface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65509647/how-can-i-do-a-brass-surface).

Comment: @Raddib76 I have specified better my problem with the result obtained...it's an important homework... can you hel me please?? My reference is http://www.it.hiof.no/~borres/j3d/explain/light/p-materials.html.. I don't understand my result

Comment: No, I can't. It is not possible with this technology. In your example, the position of the light source appears to be behind the object (Note, the view space z axis points out of the viewport), but the result will never be of good quality. If you want to use OpenGL instead of a rendering engine (Unity, Unreal, ...)), I recommend reading a good tutorial. e.g. [LearnOpenGL](https://learnopengl.com/)

Comment: Now it's good in your opinion, at least fro what it is possible to do with this old tools? I have edited the image...

Comment: This is almost the best you can get. However, you can use a higher resolution for the sphere to get some specular highlights.

Comment: You may be interested in [GLSL fixed function fragment program replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421778/glsl-fixed-function-fragment-program-replacement/45716107#45716107) and [What's the difference between Phong shading and Gouraud shading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63958531/whats-the-difference-between-phong-shading-and-gouraud-shading)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to render a green surface with a [Blinn–Phong reflection model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinn%E2%80%93Phong_reflection_model) and [Gouraud shading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouraud_shading) you have found the answer. However, you can't do anything more realistic with the 20-year-old OpenGL Fixed-Function pipeline. Same reason as in the comments on your previous question [How can I do a brass surface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65509647/how-can-i-do-a-brass-surface).
With Gouraud shading the ligh model is computed per vertex, compared to  [Phong shadding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_shading) where it is computed per fragment. Use a higher resolution on the sphere to improve lighting and get some specular highlights. See [GLSL fixed function fragment program replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421778/glsl-fixed-function-fragment-program-replacement/45716107#45716107) and [What's the difference between Phong shading and Gouraud shading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63958531/whats-the-difference-between-phong-shading-and-gouraud-shading).