# OpenGL - 3D cube - Specular spot light not showing

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl, light

I recently took on to learn OpenGL via pyOpenGL, and I've been struggling with a lot of notions, especially lighting.

I managed to create a 3D cube thanks to this [tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/coloring-pyopengl-surfaces-python-opengl/?completed=/opengl-rotating-cube-example-pyopengl-tutorial/), and I would like to make it look better with appropriate lighting. I'm especially found of the spot light specular light creates, which gives a glossy aspect to the cube.

*Desired output* (one of these, taken [here](https://learnopengl.com/Lighting/Basic-Lighting))
[image]

Here is what I do with the lights

```py
glLight(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION,  (1.1, 0., .3, 1))  # point light
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)

... draw cube ...
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, (1, 1, 1, 1))
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, 1)
glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE)
```

*what I have so far*
[image: what I have so far]

If tried increasing the shininess but above ~30 all light effect disappears.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, or simply good documentation (preferably using pyOpenGL, and without using vertex / fragment shaders).

Thanks!

Full code if needed:

```py
import pygame
from OpenGL.GL import shaders
from pygame.locals import *

from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

verticies = (
    ( 1, -1, -1), # 0
    ( 1,  1, -1), # 1
    (-1,  1, -1), # 2
    (-1, -1, -1), # 3
    ( 1, -1,  1), # 4
    ( 1,  1,  1), # 5
    (-1, -1,  1), # 6
    (-1,  1,  1), # 7
    )

surfaces = (
    (0,1,2,3),
    (3,2,7,6),
    (6,7,5,4),
    (4,5,1,0),
    (1,5,7,2),
    (4,0,3,6),
    )

normals = [
    ( 0,  0, -1),  # surface 0
    (-1,  0,  0),  # surface 1
    ( 0,  0,  1),  # surface 2
    ( 1,  0,  0),  # surface 3
    ( 0,  1,  0),  # surface 4
    ( 0, -1,  0)   # surface 5
]

colors = [(1, 0.2, 0)] * 12

edges = (
    (0,1),
    (0,3),
    (0,4),
    (2,1),
    (2,3),
    (2,7),
    (6,3),
    (6,4),
    (6,7),
    (5,1),
    (5,4),
    (5,7),
    )


def Cube():
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    for i_surface, surface in enumerate(surfaces):
        x = 0
        glNormal3fv(normals[i_surface])
        for vertex in surface:
            x += 1
            glColor3fv(colors[x])
            glVertex3fv(verticies[vertex])
    glEnd()

    glColor3fv(colors[0])
    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    for edge in edges:
        for vertex in edge:
            glVertex3fv(verticies[vertex])
    glEnd()

    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, (1, 1, 1, 1))
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, 1)
    glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE)


def main():
    global surfaces

    pygame.init()
    display = (800, 600)
    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()


    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    gluPerspective(45, (display[0]/display[1]), 0.1, 50.0)

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glTranslatef(0, 0, -5)
    # glRotatef(20, 1, 0, 0)

    glLight(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION,  (1.1, 0., .3, 1))  # point light
    # glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, (0, 0, 1, 1))
    # glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, (1, 1, 1, 1))

    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        glRotatef(0.2, 0, 1, 0)
        Cube()

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)

main()
```

Comment: What you are seeing on the example you attempt to achieve is a per fragment (or per pixel) lighting, you need shaders to do this. By using the fixed pipeline here, you are bound to "per vertex" lighting.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get the effect you want using the deprecated OpenGL light mode. The OpenGL [Blinn–Phong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinn%E2%80%93Phong_reflection_model) reflection model uses [Gouraud shading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouraud_shading) in compare to [Phong shading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_shading). While at Gouraud shading the light is calculates per vertex (Vertex shader), at Phong shading the light is calculates per fragment (fragment shader). See [what the difference between phong shading and gouraud shading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63958531/what-is-the-difference-between-phong-shading-and-gouraud-shading/63958763#63958763).
However you can get a better effect by tessellating the side faces of the cube.

If you want to implement [Phong shading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_shading), you need to use a shader program. See [GLSL fixed function fragment program replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421778/glsl-fixed-function-fragment-program-replacement/45716107#45716107)

Complete Example:

[image]

```py
import os 
import math 
import ctypes 
import glm 
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GL.shaders import *
from OpenGL.arrays import *

class MyWindow:

    __glsl_vert = """
        #version 450 core

        layout (location = 0) in vec3 a_pos;
        layout (location = 1) in vec3 a_nv;
        layout (location = 2) in vec4 a_col;

        out vec3 v_pos;
        out vec3 v_nv;
        out vec4 v_color;

        uniform mat4 u_proj; 
        uniform mat4 u_view; 
        uniform mat4 u_model; 

        void main()
        {
            mat4 model_view = u_view * u_model;
            mat3 normal     = transpose(inverse(mat3(model_view)));
            
            vec4 view_pos   = model_view * vec4(a_pos.xyz, 1.0);

            v_pos       = view_pos.xyz;
            v_nv        = normal * a_nv;  
            v_color     = a_col;
            gl_Position = u_proj * view_pos;
        }
    """

    __glsl_frag = """
        #version 450 core
        
        out vec4 frag_color;
        in  vec3 v_pos;
        in  vec3 v_nv;
        in  vec4 v_color;

        void main()
        {
            vec3  L     = normalize(vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0));
            vec3  N     = normalize(v_nv);
            vec3  V     = -normalize(v_pos);
            vec3  H     = normalize(V + L);
            float ka    = 0.1;
            float kd    = max(0.0, dot(N, L)) * 0.1;
            float NdotH = max(0.0, dot(N, H));
            float sh    = 100.0;
            float ks    = pow(NdotH, sh);
            frag_color  = vec4(v_color.rgb * (ka + kd + ks), v_color.a);
        }
    """

    def __init__(self, w, h):
        
        self.__caption = 'OpenGL Window'
        self.__vp_valid = False
        self.__vp_size = [w, h]

        glutInit()
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH)
        glutInitWindowSize(self.__vp_size[0], self.__vp_size[1])
        self.__glut_wnd = glutCreateWindow(self.__caption)

        self.__program = compileProgram( 
            compileShader( self.__glsl_vert, GL_VERTEX_SHADER ),
            compileShader( self.__glsl_frag, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER ),
        )
        self.___attrib = { a : glGetAttribLocation (self.__program, a) for a in ['a_pos', 'a_nv', 'a_col'] }
        print(self.___attrib)
        self.___uniform = { u : glGetUniformLocation (self.__program, u) for u in ['u_model', 'u_view', 'u_proj'] }
        print(self.___uniform)

        v = [[-1,-1,1], [1,-1,1], [1,1,1], [-1,1,1], [-1,-1,-1], [1,-1,-1], [1,1,-1], [-1,1,-1]]
        c = [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.5, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]
        n = [[0,0,1], [1,0,0], [0,0,-1], [-1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,-1,0]]
        e = [[0,1,2,3], [1,5,6,2], [5,4,7,6], [4,0,3,7], [3,2,6,7], [1,0,4,5]]
        index_array = [si*4+[0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3][vi] for si in range(6) for vi in range(6)]
        attr_array = []
        for si in range(len(e)):
            for vi in e[si]:
                attr_array += [*v[vi], *n[si], *c[si], 1]
        
        self.__no_vert = len(attr_array) // 10
        self.__no_indices = len(index_array)
        vertex_attributes = (ctypes.c_float * len(attr_array))(*attr_array)
        indices = (ctypes.c_uint32 * self.__no_indices)(*index_array)
        
        self.__vao = glGenVertexArrays(1)
        self.__vbo, self.__ibo = glGenBuffers(2)
        
        glBindVertexArray(self.__vao)

        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.__ibo)
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.__vbo)
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_attributes, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

        float_size = ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_float)   
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, False, 10*float_size, None)
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, False, 10*float_size, c_void_p(3*float_size))
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 4, GL_FLOAT, False, 10*float_size, c_void_p(6*float_size))
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2)

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        glUseProgram(self.__program)

        glutReshapeFunc(self.__reshape)
        glutDisplayFunc(self.__mainloop)

    def run(self):
        self.__starttime = 0
        self.__starttime = self.elapsed_ms()
        glutMainLoop()

    def elapsed_ms(self):
      return glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME) - self.__starttime

    def __reshape(self, w, h):
        self.__vp_valid = False

    def __mainloop(self):

        if not self.__vp_valid:
            self.__vp_size = [glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH), glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT)]
            self.__vp_valid = True
            glViewport(0, 0, self.__vp_size[0], self.__vp_size[1])

        proj  = glm.mat4(1)
        view  = glm.mat4(1)
        model = glm.mat4(1)

        aspect = self.__vp_size[0]/self.__vp_size[1]
        proj = glm.perspective(glm.radians(90.0), aspect, 0.1, 10.0)

        view = glm.lookAt(glm.vec3(0,-3,0), glm.vec3(0, 0, 0), glm.vec3(0,0,1))
        
        angle1 = self.elapsed_ms() * math.pi * 2 / 5000.0
        angle2 = self.elapsed_ms() * math.pi * 2 / 7333.0
        model = glm.rotate(model, angle1, glm.vec3(1, 0, 0))
        model = glm.rotate(model, angle2, glm.vec3(0, 1, 0))

        glUniformMatrix4fv(self.___uniform['u_proj'], 1, GL_FALSE, glm.value_ptr(proj) )
        glUniformMatrix4fv(self.___uniform['u_view'], 1, GL_FALSE, glm.value_ptr(view) )
        glUniformMatrix4fv(self.___uniform['u_model'], 1, GL_FALSE, glm.value_ptr(model) )

        glClearColor(0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
          
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, self.__no_indices, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, None)

        glutSwapBuffers()
        glutPostRedisplay()


window = MyWindow(800, 600)
window.run()
```

See also [Python, OpenGL 4.6, Cube](https://github.com/Rabbid76/graphics-snippets/blob/master/example/python/dsa_spirv_cube/example_python_dsa_spirv.md).

Comment: Thanks for all the documentation :)